# How to update a NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I want to ask a objective C question. I have a string retrieve from UITextField and I want to check the string contains the '@' or not. However, when I use the following code, it has some errors, can anyone help me? Thank you.

```
if([inputTextField.text rangeOfString:@"%"].location != NSNotFound)
    NSLog(@"It does not contain the %@");
else
    NSLog(@"It contains the %@");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the syntax:

> ```
> if([inputTextField.text rangeOfString:myString].location == NSNotFound)
>     NSLog(@"It does not contain the %@", myString);
> else
>     NSLog(@"It contains the %@", myString);
> ```

As you will see, the `%@` will be replaced with the content of `myString`.

Comment: You are welcome.

If you need to display the "@" then try doubling the symbol, i.e. use %@@ instead of %@. Not very sure if it will work, but you can try.

Comment: That code actually gives the wrong result. Change the "!=" comparrison to "==" to make it work correctly.

Comment: You can put an @ sign in a string without escaping it e.g. `@"The string %@ contains an @"`.  You do need to escape % though e.g. `@"The string %@ contains an %%"`

Answer (score 2):

This code should do the trick:

```
if([inputTextField.text rangeOfString:@"@"].location == NSNotFound) 
    NSLog(@"It does not contain the @"); 
else 
    NSLog(@"It contains the @");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
NSLog([NSString stringWithUTF8String: "It does not contain the @"]);
```

or just

```
NSLog(@"It contains the @");
```

Note: Inside the @"..." construct, you should only use 7-bit ASCII symbols, see [Apple's developer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/CreatingStrings.html).

Answer (score 0):

In you NSLog statement you put a %@ but no arguments after.

Comment: thank you for your reply. If I want to display the "@" in the statement, what should I do?